# How to add Position History to the Related Lists area

Tags: force.com, related-list

I'm not understanding how to add Position History to the Related Lists area. Here's what I've done:

1. From Setup I've clicked Create > Objects > Position > Page Layouts > 'Edit' Position Layout
2. From there, in the little floating edit box, I've clicked Related Lists and I expect to see 'Position History' but it is not there.

I've looked around for a lot for answers and I think my confusion arises partly because I don't totally understand what related lists are or where they come from. Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rachel,

I think in your case, what you need to do is enable the **Track Field History** feature for the Position object. You can do this by:

1. Open Setup
2. Click Create > Objects > Position
3. Click **Edit** to edit the object settings
4. Mark the **Track Field History** checkbox (screenshot below).
5. Click **Save**. The *Position History* related list should now appear as an option when you're editing Position page layouts.

[image]

A *related list* basically gives you a quick view into child records tied to the record you're looking at. For more information you could search for "parent-child relationship database" or take a look at the Wikipedia page on [hierarchical database model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model).